# Reading dates into sas from premade .dat dataset

Tags: sas

Being asked to read in and format dates in a premade sas file. Question is as follows:

> Read in BIRTHDATE and DEATHDATE to recognize them as dates. (Create new variables called birthdate2 and deathdate2 respectively).

So, i've created a copy of the dataset:

```
     data presidents_datefix;
 set myfolder.presidents1;
 run;
```

And am trying to use the input function to read the birth and deathdates in:

```
     data presidents_datefix;
     infile "presidents1"
     input Presidents $ 1-38 @2 Birthdate date9. Deathdate date9.;
 run;
```

Before running this datastep, the presidents1_datefix viewtable loads just fine. After the datastep, I get a warning message that reads:

> "WARNING: The data set WORK.PRESIDENTS_DATEFIX may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 0 variables.
> WARNING: Data set WORK.PRESIDENTS_DATEFIX was not replaced because this step was stopped."

Then, when opening the viewtable, no observations exist anymore. I also get a series of error messages that say

> ERROR 23-2: invalid option name

for every value of the input function.
Would really appreciate some help figuring out what I've done wrong and how I can fix it! Thank you!

Comment: Show the contents of the file `presidents.sas`.  You might be trying to read a SAS data set as if it were raw text data.  .sas file extension is generally used to store SAS programs (source code), and .dat or .txt files for textual data to be input (via INFILE and INPUT).

Comment: yeah sorry, i wrote that wrong--will edit momentarily. presidents1 is a dataset (.dat), not a sas program. my mistake!

Comment: The SAS log should show you where SAS detected the syntax error.  Your INFILE statement does not have an ending semi-colon.  If your data file has an extension of .dat then you should include that in the filename you use in the INFILE statement.  A SAS dataset uses .sas7bdat as the extension.  A file with .dat as an extension is just a text file (but perhaps one with some defined structure) and not a dataset.

Comment: Looks like it was a .sas7bdat. Can you tell I'm new to this? Still having issues with the error, it seems to not recognize INPUT as a valid statement.

Comment: You do not want to use INFILE and INPUT **statements** with a SAS dataset.  Just use SET or MERGE to get the data.  To me it looks like the task you were given was to use the INPUT() **function** , not the INPUT statement.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to convert your dates: https://youtu.be/KXCygvFrJqY or this post: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/how-to-convert-char-var-to-sas-date/td-p/45067